# Is biltong healthy for a lean muscle weight trainer?

Tags: snacks

Is biltong healthy for me.  I am trying to gain lean muscle but am starving all the time from all the training and I don't like protein shakes as it upsets my stomach?

Comment: For those who don't know, [biltong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biltong) is a type of cured meat similar to beef jerky but thicker and prepared differently.

Comment: What is lean muscle?

Comment: If you can't keep down protein shakes, is it because of the milk? Are you lactose intolerant? If you are not, just drink milk. If you are, take some lactase pills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to get a "yes" or "no" answer to your question. The best we can do is point out what we think is healthy or unhealthy about biltong.

Good: Fat and protein that *you* can actually keep down.

Bad: So much salt. If you are sensitive to sodium, this could be raising your blood pressure and having other side-effects.